# Multilingual documents in overleaf

Tags: babel, overleaf

Following [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Multilingual_versions) I have tried to  make multilingual version of document in overleaf. However it doesn't seem to work. Instead of printing version for main language it prints all languages at once. 
Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size
\usepackage[german, french, english]{babel} % multi-language support
\selectlanguage{english}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % for unicode input characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\babeltags{de = german, fr = french}
\textbf{Hello \textde{Hallo}}

\end{document}
```

The code results in:

[image: Code result]

Did I miss something out or Overleaf is just broken? How to do multilingual document properly?

Comment: What exactly did you expect to happen?

Comment: Did you read up on what `\textde{...}` actually is? it is shorthand for `\foreignlanguage{german}{...}` so it just typesets whatever you give it under german language settings.

Comment: If english language is the main language I expected to print "Hello" only. If I'd set german language it should print "Hello Hallo". So basically I'm trying to do a translation of document. Isn't it what those commands are supposed to do?

Comment: Oh I see then I didn't know it's just a shorthand for `\foreignlanguage`

Comment: You'd probably have to read through the babel manual. There might be some iflanguage tools. Just remember that overleaf is often behind in their package versions, so if you read about a cool new babel feature, you might not have it in overleaf.

Comment: I also learnt something: `\foreignlanguage` just changes the hypernation patters etc, not names like `\contentsname`, whereas `\selectlanguage` and the `otherlanguage` does.

Comment: Thanks for help. I was mislead by wikibooks which states "It is possible in LaTeX to typeset the content of one document in several languages and to choose upon compilation which language to output". Then after this paragraph it includes code snippet with `\babeltags` and `\textde`. The article also mentions `iflang` package to make translations though so I'll definitely take a look at it.

Comment: Always be careful with all things wiki. They are often not written by someone who knows what they are writing about. You also see this in many YT videos on how to use LaTeX, they recommend stuff that users never should do.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) The problem is not specific to Overleaf: I get the very same output when compiling your code on a local installation of TeX Live. While the wikibooks article seems to imply that code would print only the text for the selected language, it simply doesn't. As mentioned in the article, the `iflang` package has some conditionals that can be used to typeset different versions of text depending on the selected language. Here's an example in Overleaf, showing how these can be nested for multiple translations: https://www.overleaf.com/read/gtwhngjdqbby

Comment: @PaulGessler Thanks for your response. It is indeed misleading wikibooks article not a bug in overleaf or babel.

Answer (score 1):

The wikibooks article is quite misleading. `\textde` is just a shorthand for `\foreignlanguage{german}`. It doesn't involve any conditional rendering.

The proper solution for doing a translation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size

\usepackage[german, french, english]{babel} % multi-language support
\usepackage{iflang}
\newcommand{\lang}{english} % Control output language

\newcommand{\translation}[2]{\IfLanguageName{#1}{#2}{}}
\newcommand{\en}[1]{\translation{english}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ger}[1]{\translation{german}{#1}}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % for unicode input characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\lang}

Hello
\en{tank} 
\ger{Panzerkampfwagen}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've edited the Wikibooks article.