# Interactive button in PDF using LaTex?

Tags: interaction

[Multilingual documents in overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499621/multilingual-documents-in-overleaf) Using this thread I've created a bilingual document where a simple command changes the language that is rendered.

I now have to recompile the document to change languages, but I wanted to see if there is a way to make a button that will change the languages in realtime. Would this be possible?

I'm imagining a scenario: If button is pressed \selectlanguage{en} and if pressed again \selectlanguage {ger}.

Thanks for any answers, I have tried googling around, but I didnt find anything relevant that I could understand.

Example source code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9e5bbe8whu0ngt4/cv%20latex%20forum.zip?dl=0

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide an example of your document. Where should be this button? Is not simple comment/uncomment desired language in your editor?

Comment: Difficult for multi-page documents, as pagination is usually different for different languages.

Comment: I guess that you are thiking in some like the `ocgx` package (that I never used) but instead of mess with layers of text, I will do simply a section with English text in pages  1 to 10 or so, a  French section in pages 11-20, the Chinese in  pages 21-30, etc. and use `hyperref`  to have a ToC with links, or maybe links in headers of every page to jump easily from a section to another,  or a "top" link as sine notes in every title to return to ToC, ... Less  amazing, but effective.

Comment: Hello, I added source code as per request, I hope the download works without problems. My goal is to have the button just in the header of the page. As you can see it is a CV paper and here in Norway it's normal having an english version and a norwegian version. It's supposed to be 1 page only so I don't want to just add another page with translation, but that is an option. You can see there is a command for changing language and my ideal solution is that, pressing a button, changes the language of the CV to Norwegian/english. Thanks for all answers